# Installing addons on open source artifactory

Tags: artifactory

Is it possible to install addons in artifactory? 
I deployed an Artifactory docker container. 
The Artifactory UI says "Add-ons are currently disabled."

I found nowhere the reasons why the addons are disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this message is that Docker integration is only available for the PRO version of Artifactory. Activating those PRO features can only be done after purchasing a valid license from JFrog.

Comment: Thank you, is that documented somewhere?

Comment: Yes, in JFrog site. You can browse in www.jfrog.com

Comment: Doe you have a more specific link? Cant find it.

Comment: There you go:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Comparison+Matrix

Comment: `Extend Artifactory with Groovy-based User Plugins` So the reason for deactivated plugins is NOT the Docker Integration, but that its deactivated in the Non PRO version

Comment: Hi Skip, you wrote that you want to use addons, and mentioned Docker and not user plugon, therefore was my answer. Indeed User Plugins option is also disabled in the oss version as it is considered an addon feature